# How to check if two curves intersect in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, intersection, curves

I have a set of parametric curves and a reference curve, and I want to see which ones intersect the reference curve.

For example, let's say that the function1's are the parametric curves and function 2 is the reference curve.

```
function1[x_,a_]:=x^2+a
function2[x]:=1
```

How can I know which function1 for which a intersect function2 "in a clean way". I tried using FindRoot:

```
In:= FindRoot[function1[x, 1] == function2[x], {x, 1}]
Out= {x -> 1.}
```

It works well for this case, but in case it does not work, Mathematica provides me an absurd value, with an error message.

```
In[485]:= FindRoot[function1[x, 4] == function2[x], {x, 1}]

"During evaluation of In[485]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to
within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a  
sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision
digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>"

Out[485]= {x -> 3.09187*10^-6}
```

Instead of having an absurd value (in case they do not intersect) or the exact value (in case they intersect), I would like to get a "True" or "False" statement. Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: See Quiet[] to turn off the warning, and plug whatever result you get back into the equation to test.  For more discussion suggest you take this to mathematica.stackexchange.com, and provide a real example..

Comment: Look at
    Reduce[function1[x, a] == function2[x], {x}]
and think how to use that result to get what you want

Comment: Take a look at this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/121 and consider asking future questions on that site.